# How can I connect My asp.net web app with another asp.net mvc Project

Tags: c#

I have one asp.net web app solution and one asp.net mvc project what i want is to make some connection b/n this solutions using button or some link i tried this one but it didnt work

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:36321/Dashboard");
}
```

Comment: "didnt work" is not an error message or problem statement. What happened when you did this? Did you get an error? If not, what was the behaviour you experienced? On the surface there's no particular reason why it shouldn't work in principle - it's just a browser redirect. To make matters even simpler, you could just use a regular hyperlink rather than a button, and remove the need for a postback to the web app before redirecting.

Comment: Was the other project running? Your redirect looks akin to IIS Express (or some other debug server) in which case that'd need to be running as well.